# Script to edit "editedon" field of every resource in MODX Revo firing every 24h

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I need a simple script to force change `editedon` field of every resource in MODX Revo. This is what I have so far:

```
$resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource',array('parent' => 0));
$mydate = date(%c);
foreach ($resources as $res) {
    $res->set('editedon', $mydate);
    $res->save();
}
```

Just to test the script I assigned it to `OnBeforeCacheUpdate` event, so every time the cache is cleared I could check results. The problem is, that the script hangs itself on `Console running...` Like just "Hang in 'ere kid..."

What's going on?
Thank you.

**UPD:** When the script is called directly in browser I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in /path/script.php

However, some resources have their `editedon` field succesfully, but not all. Why is that?

**UPD2:** Ok, probably the script is not going to work on its own, because there are no MODX specific classes and all that inside script, but it seems to be working after I clear cache, because it is assigned to `OnBeforeCacheUpdate` event. Also I removed `array('parent' => 0)` part and it now works for every resource (not just ones without children). But how do I run it every 24 hour? Cron is not an option as the script doesn't work on its own.

Comment: Ok, got it working by using plugin `CronManager` for MODX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still talking to myself... this is the code that worked:

```
$resources = $modx->getCollection('modResource');
$mydate = date(%c);
foreach ($resources as $res) {
    $res->set('editedon', $mydate);
    $res->save();
}
```

Run it via [CronManager](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/cronmanager) extra for MODX and there you go. If anyone ever needs it.

Comment: If you have a very large site, this will conserve memory:

`$resources = $modx->getIterator('modResource');`

Your code could be massively faster with PDO or straight MySQL, but speed probably isn't that critical.

All that said, I can't think of any reason for setting an inaccurate `editedon` field in all of your resources, which is what your cron job does. MODX sets that field accurately every time you edit and save a resource.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your post.